# Where can nightly builds of OpenJDK 7 for Windows be found?

Tags: windows, java

I have searched high and low for a CI server or other source for a nightly build of OpenJDK7. I would like this so that I can track the bug fixes and performance improvements being made to hotspot for invokedynamic support.

I have found the instructions for building my own copy, but they are *not* for the faint of heart (me).

A pointer to an up-to-date build (and a source for more as the days & weeks progress) would be lovely. Anyone?

Answer (score 2):

There are no known nightlies available publicly from the OpenJDK project

This open source project provides prebuilt binaries for Mac, Linux and Windows with the IcedTea patches:
https://github.com/alexkasko/openjdk-unofficial-builds/

The downloads are at:
https://bitbucket.org/alexkasko/openjdk-unofficial-builds/downloads/

Some binaries are also available in Maven central at: 
http://mirrors.ibiblio.org/maven2/com/alexkasko/openjdk/

Answer (score 1):

The openjdk community doesn't produce binaries beyond the RI.  It's up to os/platform providers  or others  to build/produce build the binaries.